# 405 error when fetching POST request. Why I can't do a POST request when Get request is OK?

Tags: javascript, post, request, fetch-api

I'm trying to do POST request to JSON blob API (it is a simple API to store my JSON files), and I got 405 error...
I don't know why I can't do POST request, when the GOT request works fine.

Could someone help me please?
https://jsonblob.com/api

```
   const api = "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/c30c8afa-6557-11e9-acbe- 
   61e96b39ce8b"

    //it doesn't work
    fetch(api, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 'dean',
            login: 'dean',
        })
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed!')
    })
    .then(jsonResponse => {
        console.log(jsonResponse)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Request failure: ', error);
    });

   // get request works fine
   fetch(api).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
            console.log(response)
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed! ');
    })
    .then((Jsondata) => {
        console.log(Jsondata)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
    });
```

Comment: Oh, wait ... you've not read the api documentation at all - why do you have a blobid in a POST?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of that API you need to specify in the headers the json content type, this works fine:

```
fetch("https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'dean',
        login: 'dean',
    })
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
    }
    throw new Error('POST Request failed!')
})
.then(jsonResponse => {
    console.log(jsonResponse)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('POST Request failure: ', error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you read the documentation for that API, POST request does not take a blobID in the request URL - you also need to add a `content-type` request header with the value `application/json` - otherwise you'll get a 415 error

It returns a Blob ID in a response header `x-jsonblob`, so, to get the Blob ID header to use later, you'll need to access the headers

```js
const api = "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob"

fetch(api, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'dean',
        login: 'dean',
    }),
    // you also have to add this request header for that API
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        const blobID = response.headers.get('x-jsonblob');
        console.log(`POST returned a blobID = ${blobID}`);
        // return the blobID we can use to fetch the data later
        return blobID;
    }
    throw new Error('POST Request failed!')
}).then(blobID => {
   // lets do a GET to see if we get the right data
   console.log(`fetch ${api}/${blobID}`);
   return fetch(`${api}/${blobID}`)
}).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error('GET Request failed! ');
})
.then((Jsondata) => {
    console.log('Result of GET')
    console.log(Jsondata)
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('Request failure: ', error);
});
```